# weight of a group G

Tags: representation-theory

how can I found the weight of a group G ( I find the fundamental weights, but I don't know how found the  linear combination of fundamental weights that give me the  weights ). [image]

so we found the fundamentals weights of G= SU(3):   [image], [image] , but I want know  found the  linear combination of fundamental weights that give me the  weights.